# Cannot Save ~/.bash_profile file

Tags: linux, terminal, osx, bashrc, nano

As the attached picture shows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> does not save the `~/.bash_profile` file. Notice the dot on the red circle for closing the window. I also tried other editors such as vim and emacs and none worked either.
[image]

This is on Mac OS.

Comment: Use another editor: [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [vim](http://vim.org/), [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit), etc etc etc...

Comment: Also, use a function, not an alias, for something like this.

Comment: The dot also just means there is a program running in the current shell session; it doesn't really say anything about the state of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nano` is prompting you for the filename to  save your changes:

```
File Name to Write: /User/syhe5/.bash_profile
```

This is like other editors' Save and Save As features rolled into one. It defaults to the name used to open the file, so if you don't change it, you're saving the file normally.

**With your terminal window in focus, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write your changes to the file.**

If you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then after you save you'll still be in `nano` and the Terminal.app window will still show a dot in the red circle. But then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, which will quit `nano` immediately because there won't be any unsaved changes.

The other way to get to the prompt you are currently seeing is if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then it shows you:

```
Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?
```

And if you answered <kbd>Y</kbd> then you are prompted for the filename to save, just as if you had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. In that situation, once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, `nano` will quit. The exception is if `nano` encouters an error while attempting to save the file, but if it does, then it will tell you there was an error.

Note that this parallels the operation of most programs that edit files, whether they're command-line programs or graphical programs. Quitting with unsaved changes offers you the option to save and then, once you have done so, the application proceeds to close.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is exactly what I tried. Still, opening the file again shows it is unsaved. I restarted the computer and problem is still there.

Comment: @Penemonie In that case, what *does* happen when you press Enter? Does it continue to show `File Name to Write: /User/syhe5/.bash_profile`? Does it actually quit `nano` as though it had saved the file, even though the file isn't saved? Does pressing Escape cancel the attempt to save the file? If Escape works but Enter doesn't, then what happens when you press Ctrl+O and then, instead of pressing Enter, press Ctrl+M? Also, you mentioned you tried other editors and they didn't work either. Can you add more details about that? Also, can you save *other* files with `nano`, besides `.bash_profile`?

Comment: chepner's comment made me I realize that the dot only indicates "there is a program running in the current shell session". I successfully saved it but didn't correctly tested it out whether it was updated. I recently had to recover the user account on the mac so I got fairly worried and thought I actually almost screwed up the system. Many thanks!!